# How to get From Date and To Date for the current year based Old From Date and Duration(in months)

Tags: sql-server, date, date-range

E.g. I have a table(Table1) that has From Date, To Date and Duration columns.
From Date: 5/1/2019
To Date: Null
Duration: 12 Months

Now I want to calculate the From and To date based on the Date from another table(Table2).

If Table2 Date is '7/1/2020' Then From Date should be 5/1/2020 and To Date should be '4/30/2021' as '7/1/2020' is after the From Date(5/1/2019 + 12-month duration) of Table1

If Table2 Date is '7/1/2021' Then From Date should be 5/1/2021 and To Date should be '4/30/2022' as '7/1/2021' is after the From Date(5/1/2020 + 12-month duration) of Table1

and so on...

So how can I achieve this in SQL Server.

Comment: How about when `Table2 Date is 1 March 2021` ?

Comment: Your description of the issue is not clear. What is the relationship between `Table1` and `Table2` ? Please show some samples data form both of the tables and the required result

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to use a bit of `DATEFROMPARTS`:

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@YourDate),5,1) AS FromDate,
       DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@YourDate)+1,4,30) AS ToDate;
```

Though this doesn't address this requirement, but it doesn't make much sense:

> From Date: 5/1/2019 To Date: Null Duration: 12 Months

Any date to `NULL` doesn't have a "duration" of 12 months, it has an unknown duration, as `NULL` is an unknown value. I've thus assumed you want the same logic for the other 2 examples, and have an actual 12 month gap.